# value(importrange()) not converting text into number

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, importrange

**Set-up**

I'm importing the number value of a cell from one Google Sheet to another.

---

**Issue**

Using `importrange("sheet_url","cell")`, the value imports just fine. However, I can't perform any calculations with the imported value.

I thought `importrange()` imports the number value as a text, but `value(importrange("sheet_url","cell"))` which should handle texts gives a `#VALUE` error.

---

**Question**

How can I import the number value such that I can perform calculations with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in Revenue tab, cell G85:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE("1G6_3i5rSEdskNX2SLTPnQURRldbKnUrGOfsTX36YHpE"; "Paid Revenue!B12");
 "."; ",")
```

the reason is the transition from US syntax to EU syntax

`0.1` = valid number in US syntax
`0,1` = valid number in EU syntax